# php pdo success but dont enter the data to the database

Tags: php, sql, oop, pdo

I have this weird issue with my PDO/SQL. I use namespaces and classes to control things.

I use a custom PDO class which is because I also define some standard values like PDO should throw exceptions and so.

The weird issue appears when I try to create a user. I'm in the development stage on this project thereby I'm hardcoding a test login.

```
try  
{  
$user = new OOP\User\user();  
$user->setFirstname("Firstname");  
$user->setLastname("Lastname");  
$user->setUsername("Test");  
$user->setSecret(OOP\utillityClass::create_unique_hash(128));  
$user->setPassword(OOP\utillityClass::create_password("*Duh as if im studpid enought to post my password*", $user->getSecret()));  
$user->setEmail("some mail");  
$birthday = new DateTime("1990-01-01");  
$user->setBirthday($birthday);  
$user->setClass(1);  
$user->setAdded(new DateTime());  
$user->setLast_Active(new DateTime());  
$user->setActivated(true);  
$user->setIp(OOP\utillityClass::getip());  
$user->setIv(OOP\Crypt\crypt::createIv("hex"));  
$permissions = array();  
$permissions['staff'] = array();  
$permissions['staff']['read'] = 1;  
$user->setPermissions(json_encode($permissions));  
$user->save();  
}  
catch (Exception $e)  
{  
echo "Error *censored, i use slurs while debugging*:" . PHP_EOL;  
print_r($e);  
}
```

The above is the creation code.

This is the table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `class` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_active` datetime NOT NULL,
  `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `iv` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `permissions` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And here comes the insert code (note that it is the public save method that is called, but the save method call this private method since there is no user loaded, then it creates it):

```
private function insert()
{

    // We need the $CONFIG variable for sending actiovation emails \\
    global $CONFIG;

    $q = $this->PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `secret`, `email`, `birthday`, `class`, `added`, `last_active`, `activated`, `ip`, `iv`, `permissions`) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :username, :password, :secret, :email, :birthday, :class, :added, :last_active, :activated, :ip, :iv, :permissions);");


    $q->bindParam(':firstname', $this->firstname);
    $q->bindParam(':lastname', $this->lastname);
    $q->bindParam(':username', $this->username);
    $q->bindParam(':password', $this->password);
    $q->bindParam(':secret', $this->secret);
    $q->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
    $q->bindParam(':birthday', $this->birthday->format("Y-m-d"));
    $q->bindParam(':class', $this->class);
    $q->bindParam(':added', $this->added->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $q->bindParam(':last_active', $this->last_active->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $q->bindParam(':activated', $this->activated);
    $q->bindParam(':ip', $this->ip);
    $q->bindParam(':iv', $this->iv);
    $q->bindParam(':permissions', $this->permissions);

    $res = $q->execute();

    if ($q->errorCode() != 00000)
    {
        throw new \Exception("An error occured during the creation");
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now here comes the fun thing, there is no Exception or PDOException's at all, actually it passes as it should but it does not enter the data into the database, but the auto increment number increase by 1.

I really hope someone can help me out with this one since I've been trying to get this to work all day long, and I've tried to drop and recreate the database and tables, including the insert code.

On beforehand, thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Silly question, but are all your class variables being set OK?

Comment: This `$user = new OOP\User\user();` stands at being misinterpreted (I could be wrong though) wink. `User` and `user` but that's just me. Look into what `andrewsi` mentioned.

Comment: Try setting the error mode of the call with $this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); And then after that wrap the whole query execution in a try catch block rather than looking at the error code. Also if it's in a transaction you will need to commit the changes.

Comment: @andrewsi Yes, variables are set correctly, forgot to mention if I create the query manually and then enter it in phpmyadmin, then it works perfectly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That is correct, I've done it like that, the capital leters should simulate directories in my namespace, and the small only is the class names.

Comment: @x20mar As I mentioned I've created a custom class to set those automaticly when I initiated the custom PDO class. Also if you see the first code snippet I have a try catch which also catch'es those thrown in the classes.

Comment: @SørenKorsholmKjeldsen I was referring to your insert() function. Don't relay on the error code!

Comment: @x20mar I follow you mate, but yes I have already that setup, and it gives me nothing, but I have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the return value of the errorInfo function like so `var_dump($q->errorInfo());`. This gives you the error message if you really have failed in executing the query the same as if you have executed that query in an actual client tool (i.e. MySQL Workbench) of the DBMS.

Comment: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}

Still no data in the database though

Comment: You may have a NOT NULL constraint or a permission issue in your table. The only thing I think you can do is to var_dump all your variables and do an actual insert corresponding with all the variables into the DBMS's client tool. Be sure to use the same credentials you used within your PHP script. But I think that will be weird because normally DBMS's inform the client of those errors.

Comment: That sounds like it could be the cause, I'll give it a try. I'll be back with the result.